# Error -- Class ContactBatch must implement the method: System.Iterable<SObject> Database.Batchable<SObject>.start(Database.BatchableContext)

Tags: apex, batch, compile-error

I am getting error in below code.

> Class ContactBatch must implement the method: `System.Iterable<SObject> Database.Batchable<SObject>.start(Database.BatchableContext)`

Code:

```
global class ContactBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.Batcablecontext bc){
        string Query= 'Select id, Name, Fax, Email, MobilePhone, Description, Account.Name, Account.Rating, Account.Phone, Account.Industry FROM Contact';
        return database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.Batcablecontext bc, list<Contact> scope){
        integer size= scope.size();
        for(integer i=0; i<size; i++){
            contact con= scope.get(i);
            if(con.Fax== null || con.Fax==''){
                con.Fax= con.Account.Fax;
            }
        }
        update scope;

    }
    global void finish(Database.Batcablecontext bc){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a ***typo*** in the argument's type (class `Database.Batcablecontext`) in the `start()`, `execute()` and `finish()` methods. As currently written the class name is missing letter **h** in `Batcablecontext`.

Updating the incorrect occurrences to the correct one -- **`Database.BatchableContext`** in those methods will resolve the issue.

Comment: Nice catch. Odd error, though, I would have expected an "Unknown type" error instead.

Comment: @sfdcfox I sometimes have hard time to understand the exceptions and errors honestly :)

Comment: I noticed in the last major compiler upgrade (sometime last year I think?), the compiler errors became a lot more cryptic. e.g. leaving a semi-colon off at the end of a SOQL statement complains about `unexpected token '['` toward the beginning of the line. Drives me nuts.

Comment: Thankyou @JayantDas.. It's works fine for me now...